# Prevent libflashplayer.so from deleting a file?

Tags: files, data-recovery, open-files, adobe-flash

I'm trying the preview release of [Flash Player "Square"](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html) for Linux and noticed that video files are now being deleted from the `/tmp/` folder.

Yet the files are still in use (I can see them with `lsof`):

```
chromium- 8948 user   25u   REG                8,5  2599793    229908 /tmp/FlashXXStJt3K (deleted)
```

Is there a way to prevent flash from deleting them or a way to recover them?

Comment: as an alternative you might be able to create an SELinux, AppArmor, or other advanced security policy to prevent stuff from deleting stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried this before, but...

There is a link to the file in `/proc/8948/fd/`. You can catenate the file as root (it's *only* readable as root), and pipe it to a new file. Whether the file is intact, I've not verified.

Comment: Yes, even if the file appears red with ls (implying the symlink is broken) I was able to cat and pipe to a new file as root. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can even hardlink it out of there (using the ln command)

Comment: linking in current versions of linux is impossible - you can only read/write it.